# Create nested hashes in ruby and save it into JSON

Tags: json, ruby, ruby-hash

Hi I'm new in ruby and I'm trying to save a nested hash into a JSON file, the final hash looks like this:

```
{"**School**":{"*Students*":{ "Info":{},"Values":{} },"*Teachers*":{ "Info":{},"Values":{} } } }
```

But initially the hash must start empty :

```
{"**School**":{} }
```

And then I need to add elements at every level , like this :

```
{"**School**":{} ,"**Hospital**":{} }
```

And

```
{"**School**":{ "*Students*":{} } ,"**Hospital**":{} }
```

And

```
{"**School**":{ "*Students*":{ "*Info*":{ "Name": "Varchar" },"*Values*":{ "Name": "Jane" } } } ,"**Hospital**":{} }
```

I tried thing like the one below but it doesn't seem to work :

```
hash = Hash.new 

hash[ "**School**" ] = {"Student":{}} 

hash[ "**School**" ][ "Student" ] = {"Info":{},"Values":{}}


File.open("saved.json","w") do |f|

f.write(hash.to_json)
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't seem to work*? Do you get an error? An unexpected result? What is your question?

Comment: Well when I try to add the value:  "Teachers":{} to the hash

Comment: ....my code just overwrite "**Teachers**":{} where is located "**Student**":{} . And also my code duplicate the insertion getting this result  : {"**School**":{"Teachers":{},"**Teachers**":{"_Info_":{},"_Values_":{}}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
hash = Hash.new
hash[ "**School**" ] = {}
hash[ "**School**" ][ "Student" ] = {}
hash[ "**School**" ][ "Student" ]["Info"] = {}
hash[ "**School**" ][ "Student" ]["Values"] = {}
```

This will initialise your hash in desired structure with empty content.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the key of :

```
{"Student": {}}
# {:Student=>{}}
```

is

```
:Student
```

and not

```
"Student"
```

To define a string key, use:

```
{"Student" => {}}
```

`to_json` doesn't seem to care if the key is a symbol or a string, and exports them both with the same format:

```
require 'json'
puts ({a: 1, "a" => 2}.to_json)
# {"a":1,"a":2}
```

This doesn't help for debugging.